# Very confused with polynomial rings and its basis

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I am super confused with this in ideals and basis of it.

The question asks me to show that $x$ and $x+x^2, x^2$ are minimal basis of the ideal $k[x]$ the set of polynomials of one variable $x$ over some field $k$.

But even before I consider this question, I am not sure why $x$ can even be a basis for $k[x]$. How can $x$ span $k[x]$ at all?

Span($x$)=$cx$ where $c$ $\in$ $k$ and is a constant, not a polynomial coefficient, yes? while $k[x]$ involves say constant terms as well as $x^2$ or higher orders, how can Span($x$)=$cx$ produce constant, or $x^3$, $x^5$ etc?
So how can it be a basis of $k[x]$ at all??

Same goes for $x^2, x+x^2$ as a basis, how can it produce a constant term $k$ $\in$ $k[x]$ by linear combination?

I am wondering if my whole understanding of span and basis have been wrong all this time.

Can someone please explain with detail because hints and very general explanations may not clear up the core bit of the issue I am having.
Really, I am so so so confused with this.

Please please help, thank you....

Comment: I suspect the word "basis" is being used in the outdated meaning of "generating set" here.